# OpenTok | Subscribe stream error | 1600 - OTSubscriberWebRTCError

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, opentok, vonage

I have developed an app with Ionic Framework and used the plugin "cordova-plugin-opentok" v3.4.1 (last version 3.4.3 produces an error) to implement OpenTok video calls for medical consultations.

Exactly the same code was working a year ago, but the project was leaved in pending status till now, and after doing a test before an incoming presentation, the issue appears.

The error occurs when trying to subscribe to the medical professional stream, OpenTok return the next error: {"code": 1600,"message": "OTSubscriberWebRTCError"}
It should be noted that the publisher video (patient) is working ok in the same device.

In the application developed for the medical professional, that is developed in Javascript (tested in Chrome browser) it is working ok, the publisher (medical professional) and subscriber (patient) of the same call can be seen without problems.

In the Ionic mobile app (for the patient), it can be seen the video of the publisher (patient) but the professional video (subscriber) produces the mentioned error when trying to subscribe.

Currently both codes (Ionic app for patient and JS web application for medical professional) are slightly different, but at first they were exactly the same, but after the changes introduced, there were no changes regarding the error.

**PATIENT CODE (error indicated in the code):**

```
let localMediaOptions = {
    insertDefaultUI: true,
    insertMode: 'replace',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    name: patientFullName,
    fitMode: 'cover',
    facingMode: 'user',
    showControls: true,
    style: {
        nameDisplayMode: 'on',
        buttonDisplayMode: 'off',
        audioLevelDisplayMode: 'off',
        archiveStatusDisplayMode: 'off'
    },
    publishAudio: audioActive,
    publishVideo: true
};

let remoteMediaOptions = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    insertDefaultUI: true,
    insertMode: 'replace',
    fitMode: 'cover',
    showControls: true,
    style: {
        nameDisplayMode: 'on',
        buttonDisplayMode: 'off',
        audioLevelDisplayMode: 'off',
        archiveStatusDisplayMode: 'off'
    },
    subscribeToAudio: true,
    subscribeToVideo: true
};

consultationSession = OT.initSession(opentokApiKey, roomSid);

consultationSession.on({
    streamCreated: (event: any) => {
        consultationSession.subscribe(event.stream, 'remoteMedia', remoteMediaOptions, (error: any) => {
            if (error) {
                // **** HERE OCCURS THE ERROR: {"code": 1600,"message": "OTSubscriberWebRTCError"} ****
                return;
            }
            
            OT.updateViews();
        });
    },
    sessionConnected: function(event) {
        // THIS WORKS FINE
        patientVideoParticipant = OT.initPublisher('localMedia', localMediaOptions, (error: any) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log('Failed initPublisher: ', error);
                return;
            }
        });

        consultationSession.publish(patientVideoParticipant, (error: any) => {
            if (error) {
                return;
            }
        });
    }
});

consultationSession.connect(this.patientAccessToken, (error) => {
    if (error && error.message) {
        console.log('ConsultationSession | connect event error: ', error);
        return false;
    }
});
```

**MEDICAL PROFESSIONAL CODE (code working OK):**

```
var remoteMediaOptions = {
    insertDefaultUI: true,
    insertMode: 'replace',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    fitMode: 'cover',
    showControls: true,
    name: '',
    style: {
        nameDisplayMode: 'on',
        buttonDisplayMode: 'on',
        audioLevelDisplayMode: 'off',
        archiveStatusDisplayMode: 'off'
    },
    subscribeToAudio: publishAudio,
    subscribeToVideo: true
};

openTokSession = OT.initSession(apiKey, roomSid);

openTokSession.on({
    streamCreated: function(event) {
        patientSuscription = openTokSession.subscribe(event.stream, 'remoteMedia', remoteMediaOptions, function(error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('openTokSession | Error while suscribing to stream: ', error);
                return;
            }
        });
    }
});

var localMediaOptions = {
    insertDefaultUI: true,
    insertMode: 'replace',
    width: '100px',
    height: '130px',
    name: callData.professionalName,
    fitMode: 'cover',
    facingMode: 'user',
    showControls: true,
    style: {
        nameDisplayMode: 'on',
        buttonDisplayMode: 'off',
        audioLevelDisplayMode: 'off',
        archiveStatusDisplayMode: 'off'
    },
    publishAudio: publishAudio,
    publishVideo: true
};

openTokSession.connect(accessToken, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('openTokSession | Error connecting OpenTok: ', error);
        return;
    }
    
    professionalParticipant = OT.initPublisher('localMedia', localMediaOptions, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('professionalParticipant failed OT.initPublisher: ', error, Date.now());
            return;
        }
    });
    
    openTokSession.publish(professionalParticipant, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('professionalParticipant - Failed to publish: ', error, Date.now());
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: are you running the patient code and medical professional code on the same device or different devices?

Comment: Different devices. Patient code in an Ionic Framework mobile app; Medical professional in a web app (using Chrome browser).
In the professional web app I can see the video of the professional and the video of the patient; but in the Patient mobile app I can only see the patient video, occurs an erro when trying to subscribe to the professional's video.

Comment: can you share information about the mobile device you are using to test?

Comment: The device has Android v9 installed with webview v94.0.4606.85

Comment: This is will be quite hard to debug on here, you can submit a help request (https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) and someone can take a look. Make sure to include the android device (so which brand) and the above information too please.